# Magento as CAS server

Tags: php, magento, case

I am working on web application which wants to use Magento as master Auth.

Application is based on Symfony and Magento. CAS client is written on Symfony side.

I, as Magento developer, has to implement CAS server on Magento side.

Is there any module available for Magento Case Server? If not kindly guide me how can I implement this?

What I have in my mind is, hook Magento login for CAS parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Magento API don't have method for customer authentication, so you need to create custom wrapper and use standard Magento functions.
This is only simple example without password protection! Also dont use GET, send/receive data as POST or JSON objects.

1. Create file cas.php in magento web-root.
2. Add next lines:

```php
<?php

$mageFilename = getcwd() . '/app/Mage.php';
if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    echo 'Mage file not found';
    exit;
}
require $mageFilename;
Mage::app("default");

$store_id = $_GET['store_id'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

try{
   $result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($store_id)->authenticate($username, $password);
}catch( Exception $e ){
   $result = $e->getMessage();
}

echo $result;
```

Call http://store_domain.com/cas.php?store_id=1&username=user_email@domain.com&password=user_password  
You get true if login was successfull or error message if it failed.